# Ipython notebook. %pylab load error in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows-7, ipython, enthought, jupyter-notebook

I run Windows 7, Enthought Python Distribution 7.3-2 Academic.
I open a command prompt, change to my code directory and type

`U:\rsch>ipython notebook`

In a new notebook, I type `%pylab` and receive the following error:

```
In [1]: %pylab

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
U:\rsch\<ipython-input-1-5c1faa999e5b> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().magic(u'pylab')

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in magic(self, arg_s, next_input)
   1983                 self._magic_locals = sys._getframe(1).f_locals
   1984             with self.builtin_trap:
-> 1985                 result = fn(magic_args)
   1986             # Ensure we're not keeping object references around:

   1987             self._magic_locals = {}

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\magic.pyc in magic_pylab(self, s)
   3471             import_all_status = True
   3472 
-> 3473         self.shell.enable_pylab(s, import_all=import_all_status)
   3474 
   3475     def magic_tb(self, s):

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.pyc in enable_pylab(self, gui, import_all)
   2592         ns = {}
   2593         try:
-> 2594             gui = pylab_activate(ns, gui, import_all, self)
   2595         except KeyError:
   2596             error("Backend %r not supported" % gui)

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.pyc in pylab_activate(user_ns, gui, import_all, shell)
    327     itself, and will be needed next to configure IPython's gui integration.
    328     """
--> 329     gui, backend = find_gui_and_backend(gui)
    330     activate_matplotlib(backend)
    331     import_pylab(user_ns, import_all)

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\pylabtools.pyc in find_gui_and_backend(gui)
    194     """
    195 
--> 196     import matplotlib
    197 
    198     if gui and gui != 'auto':

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py in <module>()
    131 import sys, os, tempfile
    132 
--> 133 from matplotlib.rcsetup import (defaultParams,
    134                                 validate_backend,
    135                                 validate_toolbar,

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\rcsetup.py in <module>()
     17 import warnings
     18 from matplotlib.fontconfig_pattern import parse_fontconfig_pattern
---> 19 from matplotlib.colors import is_color_like
     20 
     21 #interactive_bk = ['gtk', 'gtkagg', 'gtkcairo', 'fltkagg', 'qtagg', 'qt4agg',


D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colors.py in <module>()
     50 """
     51 import re
---> 52 import numpy as np
     53 from numpy import ma
     54 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyc in <module>()
    141         return loader(*packages, **options)
    142 
--> 143     import add_newdocs
    144     __all__ = ['add_newdocs']
    145 

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py in <module>()
      7 #       core/fromnumeric.py, core/defmatrix.py up-to-date.

      8 
----> 9 from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
     10 
     11 ###############################################################################


D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py in <module>()
     11 
     12 import scimath as emath
---> 13 from polynomial import *
     14 #import convertcode

     15 from utils import *

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\polynomial.py in <module>()
     15 from numpy.lib.function_base import trim_zeros, sort_complex
     16 from numpy.lib.type_check import iscomplex, real, imag
---> 17 from numpy.linalg import eigvals, lstsq
     18 
     19 class RankWarning(UserWarning):

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py in <module>()
     46 from info import __doc__
     47 
---> 48 from linalg import *
     49 
     50 from numpy.testing import Tester

D:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py in <module>()
     21         isfinite, size, finfo, absolute, log, exp
     22 from numpy.lib import triu
---> 23 from numpy.linalg import lapack_lite
     24 from numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix import matrix_power
     25 from numpy.compat import asbytes

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified path is invalid.
```

Not sure what to do.  Thanks.

Comment: Pylab mode works just fine in ipython-QtConsole, just not in an ipython shell I start from the command prompt.

Comment: The Enthought installation provides a link to PyLab that uses the following in the shortcut "target" field:

    D:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; from IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp import launch_new_instance; sys.exit(launch_new_instance())" --pylab

Comment: From the error trace, it seems loading of numpy failed. Can you do "import numpy as np" from ipython command line without any problem? If not, then reinstalling numpy to latest version may solve the issue. "easy_install numpy==version_num".

Comment: I can use numpy just fine from every situation _except_ as described above.

Comment: I suppose you could solve the problem after installing vs redistributable.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem and here is what worked for me:

1. I made sure I call the IPython **without** "pylab"
2. I then made sure all sessions/instances (excuse me but I'm new to this :) are closed. You can do this by ctrl-C in all Terminals and in the Notebook dashboard press "shutdown" if possible.

There are probably more elegant ways to do this but this is what worked for me.

Developers, take note that many newbies might get very frustrated when the first notebook they try to run gives them an error.

Adam

Comment: If you look above, I did call ipython without pylab at first.  Do you mean that I should not call pylab at all?   

Also, I did not have anything else running at the time.  
Perhaps you could explain how you worked around not being able to use pylab mode. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're missing the Scripts directory in your system path. To check, run

```
echo %PATH%
```

from the command prompt and look for `D:\Python27\Scripts`. If it's missing, you can add it manually from the Control Panel, or using a utility like [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/download).

Comment: I checked and `D:\Python27\Scripts` is on my path. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

EPD shipped with ipython 0.12. Ipython has developed a lot since then. You should update to ipython 0.13.1 by entering "enpkg ipython", as described in more detail here: 
https://support.enthought.com/entries/22415022-Using-enpkg-to-update-EPD-packages

Comment: Doing the update made it so that ipython notebook would not even start. I had to revert back to ipython 0.12.1. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: IPython 0.12 terminal is great, but you really don't want to be on 0.12 notebook - the file format is different, there are many missing features, and there are bugs that had not yet been fixed. But it is true that there are few Windows users among the IPython developers, so there might be some Windows configuration issues that affect you but have not yet been solved. Ultimately I would think that you'd be better off solving your problem with current versions rather than with obsolete versions. If you described what exactly you did and what happened, then others could help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately these error messages arent really useful. From the message you only know that 'some dll' fails to import during the import of "lapack_lite" (part of Numpy).

You can use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see which specific DLL is causing the problem, opening "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\lapack_lite.pyd" might reveal some more information.

Comment: I ran Dependency Walker and there were no problems.